# Python - Pandas - Missing value imputation using mean or mode

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

There are two datasets: claims_data and cust_data. After merging these two datasets (final dataset - cust_claims) I have to impute the missing values with an appropriate value (i.e. mean for continuous and mode for categorical).
I wrote a UDF for imputing the missing value based on the data type. But this UDF is getting applied only on the first dataset i.e. on the claims_data and that is why I am still getting the missing values in those columns which were part of cust_data

Can anyone please explain why UDF is getting applied on the first half of the dataset (claims_data) and not on the second half (cust_data).

**UDF**

```
def missing_imputation(x, stats = 'mean'):
    if (x.dtypes == 'float64') | (x.dtypes == 'int64'):
        x = x.fillna(x.mean()) if stats == 'mean' else x.fillna(x.mode())
    return x
```

```
cust_claims = cust_claims.apply(lambda x: missing_imputation(x))
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaJLY.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c1Iz.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can create Series with `stats` variable first and pass to [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), if same count of categorical values `mode` should return multiple values, so is selected first one:

```
cust_claims = pd.DataFrame({'value': [np.nan,5,8,np.nan],
                            'aa':[np.nan,'a','a','b']})

def missing_imputation(x, stats = 'mean'):
    return x.agg(stats) if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else x.mode().iat[0]

s = cust_claims.apply(missing_imputation)
print (s)
value    6.5
aa         a
dtype: object

out = cust_claims.fillna(s)
print (out)
   value aa
0    6.5  a
1    5.0  a
2    8.0  a
3    6.5  b
```